# android custom actionbar onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar

I have setup a custom actionbar like this

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_layout);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar_bg));
```

my custom_layout contains an imagebutton how do I attack a click listener to that button.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.imagebutton).setOnClickListener(mListener); ?

Answer (score 1):

As the ActionBar is a View, I think you can call findViewById on it with the id of your ImageButton.  Then you can probably attach the OnClickListener as usual.